# How to run GUI application in a rootless docker container?

Tags: x11, docker, display

When I run `docker run -it --net=host -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY <image>` and `xhost +` on my host device, the gui applications in the docker container works well. However, when it comes to rootless dockerd (with env `DOCKER_HOST=unix://$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/docker.sock` when using docker cli), the gui applications do not work and prompts

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

So what is the difference between root and rootless docker container when connecting to the host display and how to use gui in rootless docker containers?

Answer (score 2):

In rootless Docker, the host machine cannot be reached even if you use `--net=host`.

[Rootless Mode Known limitations](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#known-limitations):

> Host network (`docker run --net=host`)
> is also namespaced inside RootlessKit.

You can display with sharing XServer socket.

```
docker run -it --volume=/tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix/ -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY <image>
```

There is no need to `xhost +`, because the UID in the rootless container is mapped to the docker execution user on the host.